# Dropzone : how to send files after a return of AJAX Call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, dropzone.js

I'm currently building a CRM php tool. Actually this tool work very well.
But there is a missing function. I want to improve this tool with an upload file system.
I found Dropzone.js.
It's what I want. But I have a problem to implement this.

My problem is that I want a return of ajax call (ie an Id of a INSERT in MySQL table), and inject this ID in url dropzone.
With this ID, I want to create directory and insert in MySQL Table a history of upload file.
The return of ajax call work well. I get the ID of insert.

So my questions:

- Is it possible to send file at this moment and not before ?
- Is it a good choice for me ?

My Form :

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="formAjoutDemande">
    [input field]
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" id="ajouterNouvelleDemande"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Ajouter</button>
</form>
```

The JQuery code after click of button “Ajouter” :

```
jQuery('#ajouterNouvelleDemande').click(function(event)
{
    [condition / verification]
    if (erreur > 0)
        return(false);
    else
    {
        var url = jQuery(location).attr('href')+'/?_ajoutDemande=true'+chaineAjoutDemande;
        jQuery.ajax(
        {
            url: url
            ,dataType: 'text'
            ,success : function(data)
            {
                if (data == 'insertionDemandeErreur')
                {
                    jQuery('#affichageResultatExecutionCommande').show();                                   jQuery('#affichageResultatExecutionCommande').load(jQuery(location).attr('href')+'/?_affichageResultatCommande=true&typeResultat=demande&erreur=true&typeCommande=ajout');
                }
                else
                {
                [HERE THE CODE TO SEND FILE WITH DROPZONE]
                jQuery('#affichageResultatExecutionCommande').show();
                jQuery('#affichageDetailsDemandeSpecifique').show();
                jQuery('#affichageFormulaireCreationDemande').hide();
                jQuery('#affichageTitreAjoutNouvelleDemande').hide();
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I read the rules before ask and i should put my code of upload file but i'm completly lost.

Maybe it's not possible and I should try to find a another way.

Thx for your answer.

Comment: You should initialize your dropzone with the `autoProcessQueue: false` option and call `processQueue()`  on your dropzone object in the ajax callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thx a lot Drys !

I'm confused, it was so simple.

At the begining, your solution doesn't work.
But in dropzone.option, I used the default option and it had:
autoQueue: false

After to have comment this line, it's working